# Error using Symfony Process in Laravel with Python

Tags: python, laravel, symfony

I am trying to run a python script using Symfony Process, but somehow it isn't working. What could be the problem? Below is the code i am using to run the python script.

```
        $process = new Process(['python', '/d/Programs/Programming/XAMPP/htdocs/Musify/public/python/script.py']);
        $process->run();
        
        if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
            throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
        }

        $data = $process->getOutput();

        dd($data);
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to use D:/ aswell but it throws an exception

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$process = new Process(['python', public_path('python/script.py')]);
```

Comment: which laravel version do you use?

Comment: I think its laravel 7

Comment: this helper exists the most of the versions, https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers, are you sure you have this script in your public folder? btw why you put it in public folder?

Comment: i don't know tbh why i put it there, i just need to store it somewhere. I just want to execute the script in a php laravel controller and get the data from the python script which is printed out back to the controller

Comment: Can you try like this: 
`$process = new Process('python python/script.py');`

Comment: i fixed it, the problem was that i just had to execute the command in the folder directly so i had to move to that folder first!

Comment: Excellent! Can you update your post to share your solution or create new answer with solution?